# Is my interpretation correct for these residuals plots?

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, residuals

In preparation for my exam, I'm trying to interpret the residuals in order to understand if the time series has been modelled correctly. Otherwise, I have to suggest an improvement.

Here is the text:

*The time series of interest is given by the daily log returns of Volkswagen stock, from 2015-01-02 to 2017-05-26. Figure 1 shows the data together with the estimated autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation functions. The time series has been modelled as a white noise:*

```
Call:
arima(x = dlVOW.F, order = c(0, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
      intercept
         -4e-04
s.e.      9e-04

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0005142: log likelihood = 1441.81, aic = -2881.63
```

The diagnostics are the following:

**Figure 1: Plot of the observed data (daily log returns of Volkswagen stock)**
[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2: Some residual diagnostics**
[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 3: Mc Leod Li test on residuals**
[image: Figure 3]

Figure 1 shows a cluster of volatility on "Oct 01 2015" and a lit bit of it between "Jan 04 2016" and "Apr 01 2016".

This is also confirmed by the plot of the standardized residuals (Figure 2 - a) because the spread of the residuals, between the values "200" and "300", is different from the other ones, which are more centred at zero-mean.

On the other hand, the ACF of residuals looks white noise because only 2 lags are outside the bounds, so the model seems suitable. (***Is correct this statement?***)

The Ljung-Box test (Figure 2 - c) shows that 3  p-values (6% of 50 lags) are below the red line. Since the confidence interval is 95%, I reject the null hypothesis: there is a little bit of serial correlation.

 ***(Is correct to reject the null hypothesis when only 6% of the p-values are below the red line?) (If the series shows some volatility, is still valid the Ljung Box test which is based on the homoskedasticity assumption?)***

Finally, looking at Figure 3, I reject the null hypothesis of the Mc Leod Li test, meaning that there is autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity in this time series (ARCH effect).

To sum up, I suggest, as a model improvement, an ARCH(p).

---

***Was my interpreting wrong? what can you suggest me to improve this analysis?***